# Using ArrayObject with iterator_apply

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

No idea why this code is failing, but it is:

```php
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['b'] = 10;
foreach ($a as $b) {  // Looping works fine
    var_dump($b);
}
iterator_apply($a, fn ($x) => var_dump($x));  // Does not work
```

Error message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in /in/DoaHu:8
```

https://3v4l.org/DoaHu

Comment: Not something I've used before, so I don't know the reason - but you need to use `iterator_apply($a, fn ($x) => var_dump($x), (array)$a);`.

Comment: @NigelRen This is going to call the callback count($a) times with only the first element of $a, isn't it?

Comment: @volkerschulz, no idea - I've never used it and not sure why I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to pass arguments.

   The documentation states:

   > [The callback] only receives the given args, so it is nullary by
   > default.

   And the "given args" refers to the third parameter of iterator_apply (which you omitted and defaults to null).
2. You need to `return true`.

   The callback needs to `return true` in order for the iteration to continue. So if you want to var_dump, use an anonymous instead of an arrow function.
3. The object must be Traversable.

   `ArrayObject` is not `Traversable`, but does implement `IteratorAggregate`, so you can `getIterator()`.

Solution:

```
$a = new ArrayObject();
$a['b'] = 10;
$a['c'] = 20;
$a['d'] = 30;
foreach ($a as $b) {
    var_dump($b);
}
$itr = $a->getIterator();
iterator_apply(
    $itr,
    function ($x) {
        var_dump($x->current());
        return true;
    },
    [$itr]
);
```

Comment: What a weird design. Are there any use cases where the first argument would be different from the first element of the third argument?

Comment: Yes, if the function accepts more than just one argument (the third argument is an array of arguments passed to the function as separate arguments).

Comment: That explains adding additional elements to the array, but not why the first would be different. I wonder why they didn't just copy the way `array_map()` works.

Comment: If you're calling a third-party function which accepts an iterator as the third argument, for example. ;)